# UIScrollView does not pass events while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I have

UIscrollView that has plenty of modules to interact with

The Problem:

1) User scrolls down

2) View starts to decelerate

3) Users sees "vote" button

4) Presses, but nothing happens

5) Presses again - works

So, ideally i would like to pass all events to the scrollview subviews, but it does not happen unless the animation is completely finished!

How can i pass it?

I was not able to find the solution. This place is the my last resort

This class is huge, so it's hard to share it.

```
 class ArticleController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
 {


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    // Content view is inside the scroll view
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!


    // Here is where content created
    func createContent()
    {
      // Inside the content there is some button with tap event (let's say)
      // It is triggered when scroll animation is finished
      // It's basic behaviour of UIScroll, that i want to bypass somehow
    }
 }
```

Thanks

P.S If you have a solution, swift is preferable  language

Comment: did u apply delegate to scrollview?

Comment: set scrollview delegate

Comment: UIScrollViewDelegate it is set, so what then?

Comment: please share code...

Comment: i put something. But understand, that there is really nothing to share. It's basic behaviour

Comment: If you want someone to help, you have to give a more specific example rather than 'there is a class and here is an instance variable or two'.

Comment: This is standard `UIScrollView` behavior to prevent accidental taps by the user while scrolling. You could be able to change this behavior setting `scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false` but I never tried to mess with this iOS standard.

Comment: It does not really help. I agree with you, but at some point it gets really tricky - user has to stop scrolling animation before getting to functionalities that are inside the scrollable area. When user is actually panning - of course, everything should be prevented, but when the view is decelerating, i think it is wise to allow interaction